# Python/Parimiko error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, sftp

I have the following script:

```
import pysftp as sftp

def sftp_send():
    try:
        s = sftp.Connection(host='****', username='****', password='****')
    remotepath = '/var/sftp/uploads'
    localpath='ds/test.txt'
    s.put(localpath, remotepath)
    s.close()

except Exception as e:
    raise e

sftp_send()
```

When run it throws a "No such file" error. When I change the 'localpath' variable to:

```
localpath = 'ds'
```

it returns a 'ds is a directory', so it identifies the path up until this point. However once I add the filename, the above error occurs. I've looked at a couple of similar questions which recommended looking at remote/local permissions, however there doesn't seem to be one conclusive answer. Any ideas?

Comment: Show us complete exception callstack. + What do you get if you call `os.stat(localpath)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`remotepath` should contain file name as well so `remotepath='/var/sftp/uploads/filename.txt'`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it's throwing the same error

Answer (score 0):

How about this!

```
import pysftp

with pysftp.Connection('hostname', username='me', password='secret') as sftp:
    with sftp.cd('public'):             # temporarily chdir to public
        sftp.put('/my/local/filename')  # upload file to public/ on remote
```

Source: https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/